# Send all the traffic within a subnet through a machine

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm running an experiment and I need to send the traffic of all machines in a subnet through a specific machine (in order to monitor all the traffic, kind of man in the middle)

Let's say I have 3 VMs (**A**,**B** and **C**) with the same IP range (`10.12.10.x`) and I want that **B** and **C** send their communication traffic through VM **A**.

I deleted the default network entry from **B** and **C** routing table and added a route for `10.12.10.0` through VM **A**, besides I accept all incoming and outgoing traffic on VM **A** via iptables, however it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea to configure this scenario with routing table/iptables manipulation or even other methods?

Comment: Om vm A you have only one network card?

Comment: Yes, I only have one network card. I can add more but it wouldn't help in this scenario since I won't be able to assign a same range IP address to two different network card of my machine!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start.

First add one more ethernet card to `VM A`. Configure new eth on `VM A` on different network with access to the rest on network, internet ...

Seup will be something like this

```
VM C

ip: 10.12.10.C 
nm: 255.255.255.xxx 
gw: 10.12.10.A

VM B

ip: 10.12.10.B
nm: 255.255.255.xxx
gw: 10.12.10.A

VM A

nic0 # eth card to the VM C and B

ip: 10.12.10.A
nm: 255.255.255.xxx

nic1 # new eth through will be route traffic out to rest of the network

ip: new_ip_from_different_range
nm: new_subnet_mask
gw: new_gw
```

Now we need to setup `VM A` to accept traffic from `VM B and C`.

The first thing to do is do enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i nic0 -o nic1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i nic1 -o nic0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nic1 -j MASQUERADE
```

On this way traffic from `nic0` can go to rest of the network through `nic1`.

Replace `nic1` and `nic0` with real name of you interfaces.

Summary

All traffic from `VM C and B` will be routed to gateway witch is `VM A` on `nic0`.
You can monitor, intercept, change, redirect ... network packets and after
that route them through `nic1` to the rest of network, internet ...

Edit 1

Topology

```
    |----------|
    |  VM C    |------
    |----------|     |
                     |   |----------|    nic0  |----------| nic1
                     |---|  switch  |----------|   VM A   |------
                     |   |----------|          |----------|
                     |
    |----------|     |
    |   VM B   |-----|
    |----------|
```

My answer is based on topology like I draw. All traffic for network 10.12.10.XXX will not be send to the gateway. Communication ends only on switch. Only traffic for any other network will be send to gateway. 
`VM A` will not receive any packet when `VM B` and `VM C` have direct communication like ssh from `VM B` to `VM C`

Also `nic1` can be in some range. Set `nic0` without gateway and `nic1` with gateway.

If you want all traffic, local and trafic to net, to go through `VM A` you must use `arp poisoning`.

Great software for this is [Ettercap](https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/index.html)

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install ettercap-graphical`.

How to is [here](http://openmaniak.com/ettercap_arp.php).

Edit 2 with elaborate

Arp poisoning is based on OSI layer 2 and completely is different the routing.
It's based on switch ASIC chip. Switch in ASIC chip pair `ip` and `mac` address.
Arp poisoning is technic to tell switch that is for any ip, in our example, mac address is mac address of `nic0`.

Ip configuration is

VM C

```
ip: 10.12.10.C 
nm: 255.255.255.xxx 
gw: 10.12.10.GW

VM B

ip: 10.12.10.B
nm: 255.255.255.xxx
gw: 10.12.10.GW

VM A

nic0

ip: 10.12.10.A
nm: 255.255.255.xxx
gw: 10.12.10.GW
```

In manual, I posted in Edit 1, you will see that after successful Arp poisoning. arp look like this

```
arp on VM C


Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
xxx.xxx.xxx.A            ether   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:aa   C                     eth0
xxx.xxx.xxx.B            ether   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:aa   C                     eth0
```

arp on VM B

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
xxx.xxx.xxx.A            ether   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:aa   C                     eth0
xxx.xxx.xxx.C            ether   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:aa   C                     eth0
```

In direct communication when switch receive packet from `VM B` directed ip address to `VM C`, they look in arp table stored in ASIC chip and make decisions to send packet to `xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.aa`. This mac address belong your `nic0` on `VM A` but switch do not known that. Your `VM A` receive packet, do something, and relay to `VM C`.

This is simplest way to explain you how Arp poisoning work.

Ettercap is one of my favorite tool :)

Comment: I don't get how we can reach to 10.12.10.x network on eth0 by other nic (nic1) of VM A  ... that being said what's the role of nic1? and how come it can redirect traffic to 10.12.10.x network?! ... If you assume VM A as a router or a gateway in this scenario, why it should send the traffic to another subnet (nic1) and then somehow manage to route the traffic to reach hosts (VM B and VM C) on its own subnet!

Comment: Thanks for elaborating with graphics. Actually I need all traffic between VM B and VM C go through VM A. In another word, they shouldn't have any routing knowledge other than gw = VM A ... I'll work on arp poisoning to see how it goes. Thx again

Comment: you have my edit 2

Comment: Thank you very much for your simple but thorough explanation of arp poisoning. Actually I worked quite a bit with Ettercap over the BackTrack. But now I'm doing an experiment to capture the traffic and  build a lightweight monitoring system on the gw (that being said VM A in this scenario) and I really appreciate your helpful comments.